# Good reasons not to use client-side validation anymore (in addition to server-side)?

Tags: validation

Looking at five or six login sections for various major 'web 2.0' sites, many of them seem to do all the validation server-side.

Can anyone provide any reasons for why none of these use client side validation *aswell* (i.e. javascript)?  A prime example would be checking for empty text boxes when the user clicks 'login' and popping up an `alert('Please enter your password and try again')`).

I'm aware it is easily circumvented/disabled, so for security reasons is pointless.

Comment: If your login and registration pages/form are simple and well designed, you should be able to get away without requiring any client side validation. I guess client side validation is really important when you are pessimistic about the user experience on your page :)

Comment: The clientside validation only saves the user the trouble of submitting data when you already know it will get rejected. Saves time for the user, and work for the server.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason not to use that kind of check. Saving your users time and frustration is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

Better yet, instead of a popup, disable the Login button (from JavaScript, not in the HTML itself, to make it degrade gracefully). Enable it only if a username and password are filled in, and display a helpful message that explains why the button is disabled. This could be as simple as the grey text "Enter your password" in the Password box.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I always try to use both, but I can think of two reasons not to use Client-side validation.

1. javascript not enabled on client
   side, therefore not possible... It's
   perfectly possible to trap whether
   js    is enabled or not, and degrade
   nicely; but it is easier simply to
   code for the lowest-common
   client-side denominator simply assuming that
   client-side validation is not possible.
2. Client performance. It's faster
   to simply
       submit the form than it is to
       validate then submit the form. It
       lacks the immediacy of cs validation
       if there are any errors to report,
       but is faster if there are no
       errors.

Comment: As to 1: With some thought (see also my post), no additional detection code is needed at all. Just consider the JavaScript as an optional add-on, and don't modify the existing form code.

Comment: As to 2: Submitting is usually a lot slower than running some simple checks. Even on a local network, I think this will usually be the case. A simple "is this field filled in" check will not take more than a millisecond.

Comment: :) I didn't say I agreed with them... but server-side-checking should always be done, so a submit/server-side-check will always be faster than a client-side-check/submit/server-side-check... if there are no errors.
If there are errors, then you have the benefit of client-side-checking to trap and demand that they're fixed before the submit... that's the benefit of using both validations; but a lazy designer/developer might decide to skip the client-side validation for the sake of a few milliseconds of performance if 95 times out of 100 there were no errors

Answer (score 0):

'cause it's pain in the *ss to write JS validation code ? :D *just leaving the room*